# Click on a link inside a frame in WebDriver

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

In makemytrip.com click on a cancellation link a new frame opens which displays 'Cancel your Flight Booking', this is a frame. In this frame, I'm trying to click a link 'close this window'. But this is not happening, in eclipse it is giving element not exist error.

this is the code,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='dialog_closepanel']//span//a[text()='close this window']")).click();
```

how do I click on this link?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-icon.ui-icon-closethick")).click();
```

Edited:

If you see a link and a icon to close the modal, try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("close this window")).click();
```

Or

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[alt=\"close\"]")).click();
```

Comment: public class Frame_demo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://www.makemytrip.com/");
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Cancellation")).click();
WebElement cframe = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='dlgov']"));
driver.switchTo().frame(cframe);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='bookingID']")).sendKeys("abcd");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span//a")).click();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); 
//this is code u can run it 2 c the error
 
}
}

Comment: Did you try switch this line **driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span//a")).click();** for this **driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-icon.ui-icon-closethick")).click();**?

Comment: What's do you see to close the modal? One icon or one link and one icon? Using Firefox on Windows I see just a icon to close the modal. But in Firefox on Mac I see a link and a icon.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public static int DEFAULT_IMPLICIT_WAIT = 30;
getElementByLocator( By.cssSelector("span.ui-icon.ui-icon-closethick")).click();
```

From this method:

```
public static WebElement getElementByLocator( By locator ) {
  long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait( 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
  WebElement we = null;
  boolean unfound = true;
  while ( unfound ) {
    try {
      we = driver.findElement( locator );
      unfound = false; // FOUND IT
    } catch ( StaleElementReferenceException e ) {                      
      unfound = true;
      try {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
      }
    }       
  } 
  // and finally the cleanup          
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait( DEFAULT_IMPLICIT_WAIT, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
  return we;
 }
```

Comment: public class Frame_demo { public static void main(String[] args) { WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); driver.get("makemytrip.com/"); driver.findElement(By.linkText("Cancellation")).click(); WebElement cframe = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='dlgov']")); driver.switchTo().frame(cframe); driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='bookingID']")).sendKeys("abcd"); driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span//a")).click(); driver.switchTo().defaultContent();  //this is code u can run it 2 c the error } }